# How to get Button label in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following lines of code in my AngularJS project.

```
<div ng-show="update">
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.uname}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.upass}}</td>
        <td><button ng-model="index" ng-click="show()" 
                     ng-value="{{x.index}}">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When Particular button is clicked I want to retrieve that button label.
For that I have written code in Show function:

```
var v = $scope.index;
alert(v);
```

But alert box is displaying "Undefined" when i click on button.
Please suggest me where I am wrong??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well... There really isn't any reason to bind the button with the ngModel directive. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: ng-model does not work on button tag

Comment: What do you mean by *button label*?

Comment: I mean I want to pass index to function from button when button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about providing your value as an argument to the onclick function ?

```
<div ng-show="update">
<table border="1">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.uname}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.upass}}</td>
        <td><button ng-click="show(x.index)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and then

```
function show(id){

    alert(id);
}
```

This should works. Also [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) does not work on button.

Comment: why you not use `id` param inside function?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I did it a bit quickly. it is fixed :D. Thx @Ankit21ks for suggesting the edit.

Answer (score 1):

under ng-click = show(item) - this gives the particular item object.

```
    function show(obj){ console.log(obj)}
```

this function give the particular clicked obj from view.

ng-model doesn't work on button.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the index of the repeat iteration to the show method like this:

```
<button ng-click="show($index)" ...
```

and use it like this:

```
function show(i){
  var v = names[i];
  alert(v);
}
```

You can see it in action here: [PLNKR DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GmkUvmdQugdyHEcz7GPq?p=preview)

> **NOTE:** if you are passing the index to the backend service the index may not match up with the actual array if you are using a filter in your view to alter/reduce the ng-repeat expression

Another option as pointed out by @Grundy is to just pass the object back, which saves you the step of having to access it from the array... (note: this is the suggested best practice)

Comment: if you pass `x` directly, you not need `names[i]`

Comment: @Grundy you are correct, I had it in my plnkr, but didn't save the right URL.... but I updated my answer to show the passing of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the button label that you have clicked on and the index of it in the list provided. Here is what you can do.

```
<div ng-repeat="buttonId in testdata2">
  <button ng-bind="buttonId" ng-click="clickedMe(buttonId, $index)"></button>
</div>




$scope.clickedMe = function(buttonId, index) {
 console.log(buttonId + " - " + index);
};
```

Have your files in local and run them.